# iPhone - comparing a character returned by characterAtIndex with another hard coded one

Tags: iphone, comparison, character, hardcode

I'd like to compare a character returned by characterAtIndex with some "hard" charaters, like @" ", or @"P". This may look stupid, but I don't find the way to do this...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use single quotes:

```
if ([@"test" characterAtIndex:1] == 'e')
```

Comment: @Oliver If you still need it **[yourString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", character]];** will append the character to the end of the string.